# How to dynamically set Flex Background (Color and Image)

Tags: apache-flex

I want to give the users the ability to set the background color or choose image to make it background (Tile, Center and Strentch). I tried couple of things with no luck such as trying to chaing a Skin object and assign it. and tried something like:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.setStyle("backgroundColor",uint(chosenColor));
```

with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Flex 3 Halo or Flex 4 Spark components?

I thought to access the top level application object, you had to cast it as an application object.  But, otherwise I would have used the exact same approach you use.

```
(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as Application).setStyle("backgroundColor",uint(chosenColor));
```

However, if you're using the Flex 4 approach, I would expect the background color to be in the Application skin class and am not sure if the style would affect that.  I haven't worked through the styling differences between skin classes and styles yet.  You may want to create a custom skin class that sets the background color based on the style in the component class.

Comment: I'm using Flex 4. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. I tried the skin approach but also I have to pass it as Class Application.setStyle("skinClass", mySkinClass); the problem here is that if I pass it as class I don't think I call pass attributes to it which is what I was as the color changes. Also, do you have a suggestion for setting background image?

Comment: I'm not sure which suggestion you were following, but I may have been unclear.  You have to set "what" as a class?  The "skinClass" attribute will always need to refer to a class.  I suggested you create a skin class that refers to it's host component to get the backgroundColor style.  Then just change the background style as you are.